# Confused about pointing fopen to a specific file (which is using a variable filename) in a specific directory

Tags: php

So I'm basically creating .txt files with unique filenames and then changing the ext. of the file to .mobileconfig. That's the overall goal but I wanted the files in a different directory, that's not my root directory.
So it's basically an HTML form, then it takes the data submitted through that form, figures out what to do with it here:

```
<?php 
    $txt = $_POST['content'];
    $UUID = $_POST['UUID'];
    $genfile = fopen('./generated/'$UUID.'.txt', w);
    file_put_contents('./generated/'$UUID.'.txt', $txt);
    rename('./generated/'$UUID.'.txt', './generated/'$UUID.'.mobileconfig');
 ?>
```

I had it working, but it was in the same directory as my other files. I've tried the code above, I've tried it using " instead of '. I've tried without the period before the /, and I've tried without the ./ all together.

Is there anything else that I could try besides just moving the .php file to another directory because I do want to set something up where it deletes all the files inside the generated folder every x amount of time.

Comment: TYPO: please becareful with concatenate strings and variables, `'./generated/'.$UUID.'.txt'` not `'./generated/'$UUID.'.txt'`. to concatenate `$UUID` between two strings, it must be by putting point befor and point after the variable

Comment: ohh that makes sense. I didn't realize that. Thanks @GNassro

Answer (score 0):

You have many syntax errors in your code.

Additionally, using `file_put_contents()` doesn't require that you open the file first.

Lastly, why create a file with a `.TXT` extension if you're going to rename it immediately afterwards?

Try this:

```
$txt = $_POST['content'];
$UUID = $_POST['UUID'];
$fname = "./generated/$UUID.mobileconfig";
file_put_contents($fname, $txt);
```

See the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) for details on variable expansion in double-quoted strings